# ¿Cómo sostengo el scroll, al recargar DIV?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, scroll

Buenas tardes tengo el siguiente código JavaScript

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).on('ready', function(){
           setTimeout(refrescarTabla, 5000); //Se llamará cada 5 segundos y se refrescarán los datos de dicha tabla que se cargan mediante la función LOAD de JQuery.
    });

    function refrescarTabla(){


        $('#refrescachat').load('chat.php?usuario=<?php echo $usuario_actual;?> #refrescachat', function(){
               //Realizar las funciones pertinentes
        });

    }

</script>
```

Es una función que me está recargando cada determinado tiempo el contenedor y lo llamo mediante el onload del body.

```
<body class="hold-transition skin-blue sidebar-mini" onLoad="setInterval('refrescarTabla()',2000);">
```

Esto es una especie de chat entonces si el usuario quiere bajar a mirar los mensajes al refrescar automatico el scroll vuelve y se sube entonces es molestoso, quiero aclarar que no quiero hacer uso de AJAX y que el contenedor simplemente me trae información de la base de datos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Código de contenedor:

```
<div id="refrescachat" class="direct-chat-messages" style=" height: 400px;">


                <?php
                $user = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['usuario']);
                $sess = $_SESSION['id'];
                $chats = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM chats WHERE de = '$user' AND para = '$sess' OR de = '$sess' AND para = '$user' order by id_cha desc");
                while($ch = mysql_fetch_array($chats)) { 

                  if($ch['de'] == $user) {$var = $user;} else {$var = $sess;}
                  $usere = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE id_use = '$var'");
                  $us = mysql_fetch_array($usere);
                ?>


                <?php if ($ch['de'] == $user) { ?>
                <!-- Message. Default to the left -->
                <div class="direct-chat-msg">
                  <div class="direct-chat-info clearfix"">
                    <span class="direct-chat-name pull-left"><?php echo $us['nombre']; ?></span>
                    <span class="direct-chat-timestamp pull-right"><?php echo $ch['fecha']; ?></span>
                  </div>
                  <!-- /.direct-chat-info -->
                  <img class="direct-chat-img" src="avatars/<?php echo $us['avatar']; ?>"><!-- /.direct-chat-img -->
                  <div class="direct-chat-text">
                    <?php echo $ch['mensaje']; ?>
                  </div>
                  <!-- /.direct-chat-text -->
                </div>
```

Comment: Puede usar la función `scrollTo('#target')` en este caso deberás agregarlo  en la función que recarga la tabla, que después de que se haya agregado el ultimo elemento hacerle un `scrollTo('ultimo elemento')`

Comment: No comprendo, recuerda que el contenedor se refresca cada determinado tiempo, entonces cuando tu bajas a ver los mensajes el scroll vuelve y se sube la idea es que se quede donde esta y siga refrescando normal.

Comment: tengo la solucion con angularjs te interesaria?

Comment: El caso, es que funcione y me expliquen a colocarlo bien por que no se usar AngularJs te lo agradecería. Recuerda sólo esto... El contenedor se refresca cada determinado tiempo mediante una función, por eso en la foto hasta se puede apreciar dos scroll por que si observas la funcion al refrescar vuelvo y llamo el contenedor por eso salen dos scroll que incluso no se como haré.